# How do I print the node creation timestamp in a computed field?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to store the node creation timestamp in a computed field. I know I should use `date_format()`, but I don't know which code should I use for the field value.

Which code should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$timestamp = date($entity->created);
```